# Calculate 30 minute averages and Seasonal averages in python?

Tags: python, excel, csv

I want to write a script computing the 30 minute averages for direct and diffuse radiation (i.e 12:00, 12:30, 1:00...). After the 30 minute averages are computed, I would need to separate the data into seasons (DJF) (MAM) (JJA) (SON). Values that equal = -99999 should be omitted.

Here is the first few lines of data. This is a very big file, with many years throughout it.

`DATE   month   day year    EST    Direct NIP   Diffuse PSP (sband corr) 
4/1/2004    4   1   2004    5:55    0.01967 1.5687
4/1/2004    4   1   2004    6:00    0.2295  5.3946
4/1/2004    4   1   2004    6:05    0.59015 13.0295
4/1/2004    4   1   2004    6:10    0.78686 23.0043
4/1/2004    4   1   2004    6:15    0.60982 20.827
4/1/2004    4   1   2004    6:20    0.80655 23.199
4/1/2004    4   1   2004    6:25    0.81309 26.951
4/1/2004    4   1   2004    6:30    0.77375 31.0062
4/1/2004    4   1   2004    6:35    0.55081 35.04
4/1/2004    4   1   2004    6:40    0.24262 41.1042
4/1/2004    4   1   2004    6:45    0.39999 46.6218
4/1/2004    4   1   2004    6:50    0.26229 52.7591
4/1/2004    4   1   2004    6:55    0.26885 67.9498`

Any idea on how I can go about this? Thank you for your support.

edit: Here is my code so far. It computed all radiation and at all times. Please note that is amateur as I am teaching myself how to code. Thank you

```
import csv
import openpyxl
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

x = [datetime(year = 2004, month = 4, day = 1),
     datetime(year = 2014, month = 11, day = 18)]
y = []
x2 = []
y2 = []

with open('tenyeardata.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile)

    firstline = True
    for row in data:
        if firstline:    #skip first line
            firstline = False
            continue

        x.append(int(row[1]))
        y.append(float(row[5]))
        x2.append(int(row[3]))
        y2.append(float(row[6]))


fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.set_title("North Carolina Radiation (Direct and Diffuse)")    
ax1.set_xlabel('time (hours)')
ax1.set_ylabel('SW (W m-2)')
print x[:10]
print y[:10]
ax1.plot(y, c='r', label='Direct')
ax1.plot(y2, c='b', label = 'Diffuse')
ax1.axis([-1, 568217, 0, 1100])
leg = ax1.legend()
plt.axis([-1, 568217, 0, 1100])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show us so that we can take a look?

Comment: I have just put my code in the original question. I hope It doesn't confuse you!

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out what you want to plot. You're filling `x` and `x2` but never using them. Do you wish to see the "Direct" and "Diffuse" data plotted against the time in every row (e.g., a y value of 0.01967 for a x value of 4/1/2004 at 5:55am)?

Comment: Yes exactly! My code plots that. The problem I am having is taking averages for 30 minute intervals and plotting them. And taking all of those averages and sorting them so that all seasonal months are together, in year order, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Consider calculating your needed plot dimensions: hourly date/time and season. Then run a `groupby()` mean aggregation for plotting:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time, datetime

data = '''DATE,month,day,year,EST,Direct NIP,Diffuse PSP (sband corr)
4/1/2004,4,1,2004,5:55,0.01967,1.5687
4/1/2004,4,1,2004,6:00,0.2295,5.3946
4/1/2004,4,1,2004,6:05,0.59015,13.0295
4/1/2004,4,1,2004,6:10,0.78686,23.0043
4/1/2004,4,1,2004,6:15,0.60982,20.827
4/1/2004,4,1,2004,6:20,0.80655,23.199
4/1/2004,4,1,2004,6:25,0.81309,26.951
4/1/2004,4,1,2004,6:30,0.77375,31.0062
4/1/2004,4,1,2004,6:35,0.55081,35.04
4/1/2004,4,1,2004,6:40,0.24262,41.1042
4/1/2004,4,1,2004,6:45,0.39999,46.6218
4/1/2004,4,1,2004,6:50,0.26229,52.7591
4/1/2004,4,1,2004,6:55,0.26885,67.9498'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))

# ADDED DATE/TIME FIELDS
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'] + ' ' + df['EST'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
df['MONTH'] = df['DATE'].dt.month

# EVERY HALF HOUR BLOCKS
df['HALF_HOUR_DATE'] = df['DATE'].apply(lambda dt: datetime.datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, dt.hour, 30*(dt.minute // 30)))
df['HALF_HOUR_TIME'] = df  apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%H:%M'))

# SEASON CONDITIONAL CALCULATION
df['SEASON'] = np.where(df['MONTH'].isin([12,1,2]), 'DJF',
                        np.where(df['MONTH'].isin([3,4,5]), 'MAM',
                                 np.where(df['MONTH'].isin([6,7,8]), 'JJA',
                                          np.where(df['MONTH'].isin([9,10,11]), 'SON', None))))

# AGGREGATE DATA           
aggdf = df[['SEASON', 'HALF_HOUR_DATE', 'Direct NIP', 'Diffuse PSP (sband corr)']].\
               groupby(['SEASON','HALF_HOUR_DATE']).mean()
```

**Output**

Updated Dataframe

```
#                   DATE  month  day  year   EST  Direct NIP  Diffuse PSP (sband corr)  MONTH      HALF_HOUR_DATE HALF_HOUR_TIME SEASON
# 0  2004-04-01 05:55:00      4    1  2004  5:55     0.01967                    1.5687      4 2004-04-01 05:30:00          05:30    MAM
# 1  2004-04-01 06:00:00      4    1  2004  6:00     0.22950                    5.3946      4 2004-04-01 06:00:00          06:00    MAM
# 2  2004-04-01 06:05:00      4    1  2004  6:05     0.59015                   13.0295      4 2004-04-01 06:00:00          06:00    MAM
# 3  2004-04-01 06:10:00      4    1  2004  6:10     0.78686                   23.0043      4 2004-04-01 06:00:00          06:00    MAM
# 4  2004-04-01 06:15:00      4    1  2004  6:15     0.60982                   20.8270      4 2004-04-01 06:00:00          06:00    MAM
# 5  2004-04-01 06:20:00      4    1  2004  6:20     0.80655                   23.1990      4 2004-04-01 06:00:00          06:00    MAM
# 6  2004-04-01 06:25:00      4    1  2004  6:25     0.81309                   26.9510      4 2004-04-01 06:00:00          06:00    MAM
# 7  2004-04-01 06:30:00      4    1  2004  6:30     0.77375                   31.0062      4 2004-04-01 06:30:00          06:30    MAM
# 8  2004-04-01 06:35:00      4    1  2004  6:35     0.55081                   35.0400      4 2004-04-01 06:30:00          06:30    MAM
# 9  2004-04-01 06:40:00      4    1  2004  6:40     0.24262                   41.1042      4 2004-04-01 06:30:00          06:30    MAM
# 10 2004-04-01 06:45:00      4    1  2004  6:45     0.39999                   46.6218      4 2004-04-01 06:30:00          06:30    MAM
# 11 2004-04-01 06:50:00      4    1  2004  6:50     0.26229                   52.7591      4 2004-04-01 06:30:00          06:30    MAM
# 12 2004-04-01 06:55:00      4    1  2004  6:55     0.26885                   67.9498      4 2004-04-01 06:30:00          06:30    MAM
```

Aggregated Groupby Dataframe

```
#                             Direct NIP  Diffuse PSP (sband corr)
# SEASON HALF_HOUR_DATE                                           
# MAM    2004-04-01 05:30:00    0.019670                  1.568700
#        2004-04-01 06:00:00    0.639328                 18.734233
#        2004-04-01 06:30:00    0.416385                 45.746850
```